How to draw a simple line from the 50th candle from last to second last candle?
I am not able to get the idea how to provide the time correctly to draw a line. I tried like
ObjectCreate('line', OBJ_HLINE, 0, 0, 2100);
which is drawing a line at the value of 2100, but it starts from 0 and spreads to the right end unlimited. How to draw the line starting from the 50th candle from last till the second last candle?
I also tried
ObjectCreate('line', OBJ_HLINE, 0, Time[50], 2100, Time[1], 2100);


You'll need a trend line and switch off the ray.
//assign parameters (2 moments in time, 2 prices (equal for Horizontal), **unique** name)
double price1    = 2100;
double price2    = price1;
datetime time1   = iTime(0,0,50);
datetime time2   = iTime(0,0,1);
string name      = "nameOnceUsedIsInvaladidForNextLinesToBeNamed";
//create the line
ObjectCreate(ChartID(),name,OBJ_TREND,0,time1,price1,time2,price2);
//switch off the ray    
ObjectSetInteger(ChartID(),name,OBJPROP_RAY,false);


This function will help you draw the Horizontal Line From the 50th candle to the 2nd last candle.
 void drawTrendLine()
 {
  datetime time1   = Time[50];
  double price1    = Close[50];
  datetime time2   = Time[1];
  double price2    = Close[50];
  ObjectDelete(ChartID(), "CustomTrendLine"); // Delete the object if already exist
  ObjectCreate(ChartID(),"CustomTrendLine",OBJ_TREND,0,time1,price1,time2,price2);
  ObjectSetInteger(ChartID(),"CustomTrendLine",OBJPROP_RAY_RIGHT,false);
 }

